# Is it possible to transfer a GA View to a GA Property?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In my organization we have this Google Analytics setup for our customers:

AccountA -> PropertyA -> View[1-35]

AccountB -> PropertyB -> View[1-x]

...

Each view has a filter such as: Hostname contains "customerWebsite.com"
Each customer has access to their own View.

We would like to have this setup:

AccountA -> PropertyA -> View1

AccountA -> PropertyB -> View1

AccountA -> PropertyC -> View1

Where each property is a customer's domain name, and then give each customer full control over their own Property.

**My question is then:** Is it possible to transfer all data from a view to a new property?
If all data is not possible, is it then possible to export a month of data from a view, and then import that to a property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to transfer all data from a view to a new property?

No once the data is in the view its there.

> If all data is not possible, is it then possible to export a month of data from a view, and then import that to a property?

You could export the data to big query or use the API to do a form of export as well.  However it is not possible to import the data into another view.  Google analytics data is inserted using HITs and theses hits cant take place in the past at least not more then a few hours in the past.

Note: There is a limit to how many views a web property can have.  If you have to many customers your going to run out.  Whats stopping customers from checking other customers data? each customer should be in its own google analytics account.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename any view or property and you can move a property into a different account if you have admin permissions over both. But if you make a new property or a new view, the data collection starts from then, and can't be backdated.